# Calling DisplayRequest.RequestRelease function in windows 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I want to turn off the display at a particular point using DisplayRequest.RequestRelease but im getting various exception. When i tried for desktop im getting "Arithmetic result exceeded 32 bits" error. In phone im getting system.excecutionEngine exception. I need to know the correct usage of this function.

Comment: When you say "at a particular point", do you mean like "at a particular time or point in code" or do you mean "at a particular pixel"? Have you looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj152725)? Also, it seems that it's not an agile call, so if you are calling it from a background thread, you may need to make sure to marshal it to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here.

1. DisplayRequest.RequestRelease is used to release a previous request to keep the display alive.  If you haven't called RequestActive before, then it won't work and will throw the exception.
2. If you are doing it to release a previous call, then it's possible that things are going wrong after a suspend operation, because you may have inadvertently called RequestRelease in your OnNavigatingFrom member.  Please see my blog for full details at [Most of my Windows 8 Apps are broken.  Yours probably are too](http://wieser-software.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/most-of-my-windows-8-apps-are-broken.html)